# Удаление элемента класса из массива Python

Tags: python

Имеется такой массив, состоящий из элементов класса Food:

```
class Food:
    def __init__(self, name, expiration):
        self.name = name
        self.expiration = expiration

    fridge = [Food("beer", 4), Food("steak", 1), Food("hamburger", 1), Food("donut", 3), Food("donut", 1), Food("donut", 6)]
```

И функция openFridge:

```
openFridge(eatFood("donut", [Food("beer", 4), Food("steak", 1), Food("hamburger", 1), Food("donut", 3), Food("donut", 1), Food("donut", 6)]))
```

Задание заключается в том, что нужно функцией

```
def eatFood(name, fridge):
```

В которую мы пошлём опредленное имя (например, удобно тестировать "donut")

```
openFridge(eatFood("donut", [Food("beer", 4), Food("steak", 1), Food("hamburger", 1), Food("donut", 3), Food("donut", 1), Food("donut", 6)]))
```

удалить этот пончик (donut) с минимальным сроком годности (expiration), не меняя порядок элементов в массиве и вернув этот массив без этого пончика.

Ответ должен быть такой:

```
Following items expires in fridge:   
beer (expires in 4 days)
steak (expires in 1 days)
hamburger (expires in 1 days)
donut (expires in 3 days)
donut (expires in 6 days)
```

Comment: В питоне, если мне не изменяет память, при написании составных имён принято использовать snake case. То есть `open_frige`, а не `openFrige`. Это так, кстати.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно найти минимальный срок годности для искомого продукта

```
min_expiration = min([x.expiration for x in fridge if x.name == name])
```

Затем нужно перебрать холодильник, убрав из него соответствующий критерию продукт

```
[x for x in fridge if not (x.name == name and x.expiration == min_expiration)]
```

Из условия задачи не ясно, что делать в случае, если несколько продуктов имеют одинаковый срок годности, поэтому я считаю, что таких продуктов в холодильнике нет.

Таким образом функция eatFood будет выглядеть так:

```
def eatFood(name, fridge):
  min_expiration = min([x.expiration for x in fridge if x.name == name])
  return [x for x in fridge if not(x.name == name and x.expiration == min_expiration)]
```

В функции openFridge вам остается только перебрать продукты в цикле for food in fridge и вывести на печать их поля.